# local variable referenced before assignment. python

Tags: python

i wrote the following function:

```
def get_running_time(test):
for line in PERFORMANCE_FILE:
    print(test_time)
    line_rr = line.split()
    test_time = int(line_rr[-2])
    print(test_time)
return test_time
```

and i get the error:

```
"local variable 'test_time' referenced before assignment"
```

i saw all of the solutions relay on globals but i dont want to use that.
i tried using globals but it makes things more complicated for me because when i call the function "get running time" it does not consider the initialization of "test_time" in the beginning and the global remains the same number through out the entire running of the program.
 is there another way to solve this?
thanks.

Comment: That is very odd. You should be getting `IndentationError` already at the `for`. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `UnboundLocalError` is because the iterator `PERFOMANCE_FILE` could be empty, in that case the iteration by `for` never happens, in that case `test_time` never gets set (as its being set inside the loop only).

But as you are returning `test_time` the `UnboundLocalError` is being raised. You can instead set a default at top to return when `PERFOMANCE_FILE` is empty:

```
def get_running_time(test):
    test_time = ''  # Default
    for line in PERFORMANCE_FILE:
        print(test_time)
        line_rr = line.split()
        test_time = int(line_rr[-2])
        print(test_time)
    return test_time
```

Comment: now i get the error:    test_time = int(line_rr[-2])
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @Adamso Thats a totally different thing. I'm gonna give you a hint -- `len(line_rr)` must be 1 for the line the error is being shown. And you need to catch the exception or check the list length beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_running_time(test):
    for line in PERFORMANCE_FILE:
        #test_time is not defined here on the first loop so you can't print it
        line_rr = line.split()
        test_time = int(line_rr[-2])
        print(test_time)
    return test_time
```

Comment: Not quite. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51466792/3789550)